# Type of reference to boost::filtered_range value

Tags: c++, boost

I want to add an operator[] to boost::filtered_range class.
There is my code:

```
template <typename TPredicate, typename TRange>
class my_filtered_range : public boost::filtered_range<TPredicate, TRange>
{
public:
    my_filtered_range(TPredicate Predicate, TRange &Range) : boost::filtered_range<TPredicate, TRange>(Predicate, Range)
    {
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return std::distance(begin(), end());
    }

    ???? &operator[](size_t Index) const
    {
        assert(Index < size());
        auto It = begin();
        std::advance(It, Index);
        return *It;
    }
};
```

The question is what type to use as return type for operator[]?
Specifiyng 'value_type' doesn't allow to use class with 'const' containers, "decltype(*begin())" doesn't compile with my VC++2013.

Comment: Have you tried `auto` with the `decltype` in a trailing return type ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `boost::range_reference<>` trait on the base class.

<kbd>**[Live On  Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/929c80324665e86f)**</kbd>

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

template <typename TPredicate, typename TRange>
class my_filtered_range : public boost::filtered_range<TPredicate, TRange>
{
public:
    typedef boost::filtered_range<TPredicate, TRange> base_type;

    my_filtered_range(TPredicate Predicate, TRange &Range) : boost::filtered_range<TPredicate, TRange>(Predicate, Range)
    {
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return std::distance(this->begin(), this->end());
    }

    typename boost::range_reference<const base_type>::type operator[](size_t Index) const
    {
        assert(Index < this->size());
        auto It = this->begin();
        std::advance(It, Index);
        return *It;
    }
};
```

Note how I detected you are using a broken compiler (MSVC) so I added the necessary qualifications to dependent base members and types.

Comment: Thanks for solution. "base_type" is private, I used boost::range_reference<TRance> and it works.

Comment: Erm. @Raider, `base_type` is **not** private. I _define_ it in my very own sample! You can probably assume it'll be the same for the underlying rangem but why assume when you can make it generically correct?

Comment: Got it! Sorry for my inattention.